# How do I programmatically remove a block?

Tags: blocks, 8

I have a custom module that is intended to be deployed as a pure web view, with no styling whatsoever beyond what I created in the .twig file.

I installed the Stark theme and in my local instance I went to *Admin > Structure > Block layout* to manually remove all the active blocks.

However, this module will be deployed and I will have to have it programmatically remove all blocks when integrated into the mobile client.

Is there a way to turn off any automatic/default activation of blocks?

Comment: Did you consider a custom theme that doesn't render any regions? So your page.html.twig only contains something like `{{ page.content }}` and nothing else?

Comment: Either that, or a custom page--path.html.twig that doesn't print those regions, hook_block_access() on your module on those pages or just build your own output with your own custom twig template and return it as a plain Response object.

Comment: @marcvangend - Thanks. I did try that a couple of different ways (altering page.html.twig and using hook_page_alter to unset all other regions) and unfortunately all the blocks just moved over to the content block. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use hook_preprocess_html(). For example, to remove the system navigation block from the "sidebar_first" region, define the following hook in your MODULE.module:

```
function MODULE_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  if($variables['page']['REGION']['BLOCK'])
    $variables['page']['REGION']['BLOCK']['#access'] = FALSE;
}
```

with REGION = sidebar_first and BLOCK = system_navigation.